# How to login authentication with saved encrypted data using file(basically digital certificate) in laravel 5.1

Tags: database, authentication, encryption, laravel-5.1

I want to login with a file that contains digital certificate of someone, first registers with certificate contents that is base64 format, and when registering it will encrypt the content of certificate and save into database and when login with this file, i want to login with that data matched by decrypted way, pls help how to do this? And also when i encrypt each time file content saved with different characters, is it possible to save 3323 characters in database? pls help.....

```
// controller
 $main_file = $request->file;
    //$con = $main_file->getClientOriginalName();
    $con = file_get_contents($main_file->getRealPath());
    $files = Crypt::encrypt($con);
    dd($files);
    $file = Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
    $contents = File::get($main_file);

     dd($contents);
```

Now to authenticate with this saved encrypted data, what is the possible way to save the encrypted 3322 characters in database, i am really in a stuck. can anyone help me...the main task is to login with file contents..thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're trying to implement some kind of shared private key authentication. It's not clear **why** you want to do that (more on that later), but it sounds like a bad idea right from the start because you are immediately confronted with a difficult problem: how do you get the private key from the client to the server in a secure way?

A better way to do it would be a private/public key system, similar to the sort of thing SSH does when you set up [passwordless login](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/). Basically (very basically - I'm not an expert) the idea is that the client generates a private/public key pair and then sends the public key to the server. On authentication, the private key is used to encrypt a message. This encrypted message is sent to the server, where the public key is used to decrypt it. If the correct message was received, then the client is authenticated.

Rather than having some sort of shared certificate, I'd recommend following this model. That way you don't have to share sensitive information (the client's private key) with the server.

Ultimately, you need to think about **why** you want to do this.

1. You think this will be more convenient for clients? Well, for SSH, it certainly is more convenient to log in this way, because SSH has a mechanism for automatically encrypting and passing messages in a secure way. For HTTP? Not so much. The user is going to need to generate a file then use an upload form just to log in. Passwords are much quicker and easier.
2. You think it will be more secure? The way you've described it (a shared private key) will probably be **less** secure because you somehow have to get the private key from the client to the server without it being compromised - remember, if the private key is compromised, anyone can impersonate the client. The way SSH does it is more secure because the private key never leaves the client.

Ultimately, I think you can probably get what you're looking for with a) strictly enforced password complexity rules and b) HTTPS.

If security on your site is so important that you cannot rely on HTTPS and complex passwords, then you should probably be looking at a more comprehensive solution that will encrypt all traffic between the client and the server, such as a VPN (virtual private network).

Comment: thanks for your answers and suggestions...your vote is for password based authentication that is the best way for authentication system..i am a newbie but not new in password based authentication..thanks.. @Kryten